# How to execute a sample just before thread shutdown in Jmeter?

Tags: database, jmeter, teardown

Is there a way in Jmeter to execute a sample just before thread shutdown?

For example, I have a test plan that inserts data into a database and autocommit is disabled on the connection. Each thread spawns its own connection to the database. Plan runs on a schedule (i.e. I don't know samples count) and I want to commit all inserted rows at the end of the test. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is going for [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) which is designed for performing clean-up actions.

---

The harder way is to add a separate [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 thread and 1 iteration and 1 [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
class ShutdownListener implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       //your code which needs to be executed before test ends
   }     
}

new ShutdownListener().run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately both of these would not work, because once thread is down DB connection will be closed and all uncommitted changes will be lost. That's why I need to do "clean up" in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the commit sample based on some if condition w.r.t duration or iterationnum
For ex: if you are supposed to run 100 iterations :
An If controller with the condition -
__groovy(${__iterationNum}==100)

should help.

Comment: Please, read the question carefully `Plan runs on a schedule (i.e. I don't know samples count) `, so I can't use what you have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

ok this might not be the most optimal but could be workable

- Add the following code in a JSRSampler inside a onceonly controller

def scenarioStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
def timeLimit= ctx.getThreadGroup().getDuration()-10; //Timelimit to execute the commit sampler
vars.put("scenarioStartTime",scenarioStartTime.toString());
vars.put("timeLimit",timeLimit.toString());

- Now after your DB insert sampler add the following condition in a if controller and add the commit sampler.

${__groovy(System.currentTimeMillis()-Long.valueOf(vars.get("scenarioStartTime"))>=Long.valueOf(vars.get("timeLimit"))*1000)}

This condition should let you execute the commit sampler just before the end of test duration.